# Spring MVC something like OptimisticLocking in the controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a Spring controller and two methods that one prepare order data for user to edit, the other merage the latest order information change come back from the form (POST).

Now I want to make some procedure working like `OptiMistic Locking` without add version column in database. Because client take sometime to edit the order before session expires, I have to make the post method to be sure the order is still on the same status when client first open the order edit page

So I add a `orderStatus` attribute to carry the original status before order edit page is loaded and compare with the latest status from DB when save the order edit, like this:

```
@RequestMapping("/order")
@Controller
public class OrderController{
    private String orderStatus;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{orderId}/edit", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String prepareOrderEditForm(....){
         ....
        // remember the original status
        orderStatus = Order.getLatestStatus(orderId);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/processEdit", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String prepareOrderEditForm(....){
         ....
        String currentOrderStatus = Order.getLatestStatus(orderId);
        // compare most recent status with the original status
        if(currentOrderStatus.equals(orderStatus) == false){
            ....//something is wrong, someone may be already edit the order
            return "failed";
        }else{
            orderService.merge(order);
            orderStatus = order.getNewStatus();
        }

        return "updated";
    }
}
```

I understand this design is not as robust as Optimistic locking by database it may ignore the time when DML executed, also the orderStatus here should use getter/setter as java bean. So please exclude above concern but put the scope only within this controller

My question is, as Spring MVC is working in single thread like JSP Servlet, is there any problem while multiple user log on to the spring web application and edit the same order so orderStatus in this controller class somehow intertwined by multiple user(concurrency issue)?

Answer (score 0):

Neither JSP nor Spring MVC are single threaded.

You should always try not to change instance/static variables in your controller methods.

**Edit:**

I should have mentioned that session thread safety will only work when you set Spring MVC abstract controller's synchronizeOnSession to true (by default it is false).

In your case you can:

1) set synchronizeOnSession to true in your spring application context where you define your controller.

2) Extend from Spring's AbstractController and override handleRequestInternal method.

3) in handleRequestInternal call request.getSession().setAttribute("orderStatus")

Comment: Thanks, does the "store" (`request.setSession(orderStatus)`) part is safe in concurrent situation?

Comment: I should have mentioned that session thread safety will only work when you set Spring MVC abstract controller's synchronizeOnSession to true (by default it is false).  
If you case you can:

1) set synchronizeOnSession to true in your spring application context where you define your controller.

2) Extend from Spring's AbstractController and override handleRequestInternal method.

3) in handleRequestInternal call request.getSession().setAttribute("orderStatus")

Comment: Thanks. Could you please add above comment to your answer so I will mark it as accepted answer :)